# Date.toLocaleDateString() return different output in different browsers same OS and settings

Tags: javascript, date, cross-browser

Date.toLocaleDateString() returns different output in different browsers Eg.

Open https://www.google.cz/ in Safari and Chrome

Execute below code in console

```
new Date('2016-10-01').toLocaleDateString(["cs-CZ"], {year: "numeric", month: "long", timeZone: "UTC"});
```

Check the output[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) to provide the same functionality on different systems. The minimized package is about 14k, so if you do not care about additional loading time this would be a solution.

Comment: NO the project I am working is too sensitive to add more libraries for just a small functionality. thanks aneways